# Аналоги WebBrowser для создания текстового редактора

Tags: c#, winforms

Доброго времени суток.

Пишу что-то "типо" смеси корпоративного почтового клиента и icq. Для ввода/отображения текста сообщений/уведомлений использую компонент WebBrowser (далее wb). Почему именно его:

1. html более приятен для восприятия и обработки чем rtf (RichTextBox)
2. Пользователям приходит много информации из базы по рабочим моментам в виде "Документ | Проблема | Ответственный | Возможное действие | Время до действия" - html-таблицы делают восприятие информации более приятной + в sql приятнее и удобнее формировать таблицу
3. В перспективе часть интерфейса и функционала можно переложить на плечи html, css и js

Так вот - текст прекрасно пишется/отправляется/форматируется, картинки вставляются, таблицы выводятся, благодаря html+css+js можно много разных штуковин накрутить по сравнению с rtf, но есть несколько "НО":

1. Много функционала для текстового редактора приходится костылизировать
2. Проблемы с использованием js и отловом html-событий wb
3. Глючность wb самого по себе

В связи с этим вопрос - есть ли browser-аналоги wb, позволяющие редактировать DOM и использовать компонент, как редактор текста, в которых будет чуть меньше костылей, глюков, возможностей? Все примеры за время занятия этой задачей (около года) были на wb, и то - их можно по пальцам пересчитать.

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробовал разные. Вот те, что хорошо себя показали и работают на сегодняшний день:

1) **CefSharp** [gitHub](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) - бесплатный

Сделан на основе chromium. Неплохо обновляться. У него хорошая поддержка JS. В добавок можно вызывать из Js методы в c#. Средства работы с Dom только через js.Для этого кстати есть встроеный "DevTools".

2) **DotNetBrowser** [сайт](http://dotnetbrowser-support.teamdev.com/home) - платный

Основан тоже на chromium. В документации есть поддержка манипулирования Dom, но я ею не пользовался.

Comment: не подскажете, у них есть поддержка визуального редактирования, как у wb(DesignMode = true)?